# How to fix cors in react js app deployed on heroku and spring boot app deployed on heroku

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku, cors

I have a problem with my front-end and back-end applications. I have a React.js application running for the front-end and a Java Spring Boot application running to which the React app is making calls. When they both run on my localhost, everything works fine. I run the development React app on localhost:3000 and the Spring Boot application on localhost:8080. In my controller I put the `@CrossOrigin` annotation, which makes it able for the React app to call to the Spring Boot application. This all works perfectly fine.

But now I want to deploy both apps to heroku and make them work together. Since they are separate repositories, I deployed them separately to two heroku apps. These work perfectly fine on their own. I can even make API calls to the Spring Boot application from Postman. So everything seems to work.

But when I try to call the Spring Boot heroku app from the React heroku app, this doesn't work. The issue is probably occurring due to CORS not being configured properly. But somehow I just can't make it work. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

This is one of the controllers I use:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://https://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/klanten")
public class KlantController {

    @Autowired
    private KlantService klantService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<KlantResponse> alleKlanten() {
        return this.klantService.alleKlanten();
    }    
}
```

This are the dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

package.json in React app:

```
{
"name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "ws": true
    }
  }
}
```

And finally where the axios call is made:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const KLANTEN_REST_API_URL = ' https://localhost:8080/api/klanten';

class KlantService {
  getKlanten() {
    return axios.get(KLANTEN_REST_API_URL);
  }
}

export default new KlantService();
```

How do I solve my problem?

Comment: You have changed the localhost API endpoint to your deployed link, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the issue is that it is not necessary to send an https request to your localhost. An http request is sufficient.

When it came down to the CrossOrigin annotation, putting a * in there instead of an url did the trick for me.

Since I am using this in a proof of concept, it works fine, but it is not secure. Just totally not. So I would not recommend using a * for real.